# best way to iterate over all mongoid fields

Tags: ruby, validation, mongodb, mongoid, sanitization

Say I have a mongoid class

```
Class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :username, type: String
    field :age, type: Integer

    before_save :remove_whitespace

    def remove_whitespace
        self.username.strip!
        self.age.strip!
    end
end
```

In the method `remove_whitespace`; is there a better way to iterate over all the fields to strip them off using blocks and iterators instead of typing each field separately (`self.username.strip!`)? I have about fifteen fields in my class and was looking for a elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't there an `attributes` method?

```
attributes.each {|attr| attr.strip!}
```

or

```
attributes.each do |attr_name, value|
  write_attribute(attr_name, value.strip)
end
```